# Como cancelar ação com tecla

Tags: c#

Como cancela uma ação, o código abaixo é só um **exemplo**:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Digite algo");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
                            switch (){
```

> ```
>     case "comando": //
>
> > Aqui seria para cancelar com a tecla ESC, e voltar para a primeira
> > linha do código
> ```

```
    Console.WriteLine("Digite algo");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Digite outra coisa");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Tem várias formas, só com esse trecho fica difícil ajudar, tem que ver como está fazendo. Na verdade não sei nem se está claro o que deseja em detalhes. A melhor forma depende dos detalhes.

Comment: No caso seria só cancelar o case, e voltar ao  Console.WriteLine("Digite algo"); só isso

Comment: Defina cancelar o `case`. programação é detalhe, se você não fornecer detalhes fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Tipo, o usuário digitou "comando" sem querer no console, ai ele quer voltar a digitar outro case, então teria que cancelar para ele digitar.

Comment: @LeonardoAraujo A execução vai terminar antes do usuário conseguir digitar o "comando de cancelar".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei sua pergunta bem confusa, mas pelo comentário que você fez, acho que quer algo tipo o código abaixo:

```
string text = string.Empty;

do{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite algo");
    text = Console.ReadLine();
} while (text != "alguma_coisa_invalida");

switch (text){
    case "alguma_coisa_valida":
        //todo
        break;
    case "outra_coisa_valida":
        //todo
        break;
    case "mais_uma_coisa_valida":
        //todo
        break;
    default:
        //todo
        break;
}
```

explicando: o código lê a entrada do usuário e valida se é algo aceito. Se for, entra no case, se não, continua esperando uma entrada *ok*.

Comment: É que eu queria de outro jeito, mas esse também serve

Comment: Tem como fazer com todos os cases que eu quiser colocar?

Comment: @LeonardoAraujo, editei a resposta

Comment: Parece que não está lendo os outros cases, por exemplo: case "alguma_coisa_invalida" aparece uma mensagem, mas case "outra_coisa_valida" não nenhuma mensagem

Comment: talvez o problema seja que você não compreende bem o funcionamento do _switch_. Se ele entrar no primeiro _case_ ele não vai entrar no segundo, e assim sucessivamente. Dá uma lida no https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/06tc147t(v=vs.100).aspx